# How do I force Windows 10 to see a network as private?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

My laptop has Wi-Fi and Ethernet (when docked). For some reason Wi-Fi comes up as *Private network*, and docked comes up as *Public*. In neither case did I set either as *Private* or *Public*.

Where do I set this on Windows 10? It seems like I am missing something here...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think that the easiest method to change your network to Private is through the Registry Editor:

> 1. Do a search for **regedit**, then right-click and **Run as administrator**
> 2. If necessary, acknowledge the UAC prompt
> 3. Navigate to the following location:
>      `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles`
>
>    [image: Profiles]
> 4. Expand the **Profiles** key and navigate through each GUID key below that, noting the corresponding **ProfileName** on the right:
>
>    [image: ProfileName]
> 5. When you find the **ProfileName** of the network you want to change to Private, double-click on the **Category** DWORD on the right-hand
>      side:
>
>    [image: Category]
> 6. Change the ‘Value data’ from **0** (Public) to **1** (Private):
>
>    [image: DWORD]
> 7. Close the Registry Editor
> 8. Reboot

(Source: [How to Set Network Location to be Public or Private in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6815-network-location-set-private-public-windows-10-a.html))

Comment: Always glad to help!

Comment: Next time I hear how MS-Windows is so pointy and clicky, with so many helpful buttons and wizards, eager to help you in any way; and how much of a dinosaur are all those obsolete command and shell-based operating systems, like Linux, are -- and how even the simplest things require arcane knowledge of shell scripting and magic incantations, I'm going to refer to this bookmarked question...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Eh... the "Make this PC discoverable" option [exists](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6815-network-location-set-private-public-windows-10-a.html#option1). It's not like either OS really forces you to use a GUI or various CLI(-like) methods; both are options.

Comment: Hacking the registry since 1992...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Wasn't this configurable from the GUI in W7?

Comment: @Bob , that is a good point about the "Make this PC discoverable" option.  However, many of the people that I know are utilizing a Hyper-V virtual switch and/or have their `UAC` set to *Always notify*.  As a result, that seems to add unnecessary layers of complexity to that option.  That's why I usually teach the `Registry Editor` method... it stands on its own merits.

Comment: This answer should show the GUI version as well.  Running regedit seems unusually complicated.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Who says that? Ubuntu is essentially just MacOS minus some peculiar software. I certainly don't see anybody saying MacOS is non user-friendly.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing" class="soup-https-fixed). You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: @DavidPostill , absolutely… I am always ready & willing to cite my original source.  Occasionally, I make judgment calls if I feel that I paraphrased and customized the source narrative to the point that it should be a simple hyperlink reference, rather than a block quote.  This was one of those scenarios, and my apologies if the consensus feels that I should have gone the other way.

Comment: I found the right profile, the only public one that had a creation date smaller than the date of last use. After restarting it becomes a private network but, Windows will soon go back to treating it as public one (eg "enable print and file sharing on all public networks?")

Comment: @JimB Setting the registry key makes the network `private` and enables `Make this PC discoverable`. But enabling `Make this PC discoverable` from GUI does not set the network as `private`. Although turning it off sets it back to `public`. Talk about consistent behavior :D

Answer (score 39):

The following small PowerShell script can do the same (it also requires administrator privileges).

It will list all non-private profiles and ask for confirmation to change them to private.

```
## Change NetWorkConnection Category to Private
#Requires -RunasAdministrator

Get-NetConnectionProfile |
  Where{ $_.NetWorkCategory -ne 'Private'} |
  ForEach {
    $_
    $_|Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetWorkCategory Private -Confirm
  }
```

Sample output on my German locale system:

```
Name             : Netzwerk
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
InterfaceIndex   : 3
NetworkCategory  : Public
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : Internet

Bestätigung
Möchten Sie diese Aktion wirklich ausführen?
[J] Ja  [A] Ja, alle  [N] Nein  [K] Nein, keine  [H] Anhalten  [?] Hilfe (Standard ist "J"): K
```

**Edit** This is the English confirmation text:

```
Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): n
```

Comment: @InquisitorShm Thanks for the headsup, just appended the English confirmation text.

Comment: This was great! I couldn't use regedit to find my "unidentified network" that was created by Hyper-V.

Comment: This will make every saved network private. I've already set the key to private for this network but all my networks are enumerated as "network", "network 1" etc which bear no resemblance to my SSID. So you win.

Answer (score 21):

You could use a Powershell command to perform this:

1. <kbd>WIN+R</kbd>
2. Type `powershell.exe` and hit <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd> (Opens as Administrator)
3. Paste in the following command (replacing `Network_Name` with the chosen network)

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "Network_Name" -NetworkCategory Private
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing? It looks to me like it's setting _Everything_ to private which would be the same as 'Home' I believe?

Comment: Sorry I typed <Network Name> and it was removed for some reason. Updated answer.

Comment: You must run it as administrator. and Thanks

Comment: This is a nicer option than using regedit, and has the bonus of working with unidentified networks (which Settings app and regedit don't seem to support). Although, I had to run PowerShell as Administrator to get it to work (press Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of just Enter).

Answer (score 10):

If you're not already on *a* private network, this is the quickest and easiest way:

1. Open a File Explorer window.
2. Click **Network** in the left-hand navigation pane.
3. Click OK to the error message.
4. Click the yellow infobar and then **Turn on network discovery and file sharing**.
5. Click **No, make the network I am connected to a private network**.

Alternatively, you can use PowerShell:

1. Run PowerShell as administrator.
2. Type this command to make all connections private:

   ```
   Get-NetConnectionProfile | Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private
   ```

If you have multiple connections and you'd like some not to be private, you can set them selectively:

1. Get current networks:

```
PS C:\> Get-NetConnectionProfile

Name             : Network
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 1
InterfaceIndex   : 11
NetworkCategory  : Public
IPv4Connectivity : LocalNetwork
IPv6Connectivity : LocalNetwork

Name             : Unidentified network
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 2
InterfaceIndex   : 4
NetworkCategory  : Public
IPv4Connectivity : LocalNetwork
IPv6Connectivity : LocalNetwork
```

2. Change the desired network:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet 1" -NetworkCategory Private
```

Note that you can never manually change a connection profile to the network category `DomainAuthenticated`. If you have an interface that should be set to this but isn't, you have a bigger domain connectivity issue at play.

Comment: Wow, easily the best answer.  Took 5 seconds, no scary commands or registry changes.

Comment: Get-NetConnectionProfile does not show me disconnected networks that I can find at registry key: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles", so this code only works for the connected networks

Comment: The commands for making a _specific_ adapter private are great - much better than wholesale marking unidentified connections private as in other answers (\*shudder\*).

Comment: So elegant, thank you! Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 8/8.1 Microsoft moved those settings to the **new** settings app.  I personally don't like it.  These instructions are for wired Ethernet connections.  I can't find a setting for individual Wi-Fi networks.

In Windows 10, the same settings app has the setting you need to point and click to make it a public or private network.

1. Click on the start button and type **settings** and open up the Settings App.
2. Select **Network & Internet**
3. Select **Ethernet**
4. Select the adapter you want to change the setting for.
5. Make this PC discoverable should be set to **On** for private networking.

[image: Steps to accomplish this]

Comment: A very good tutorial, but there are a pair of very important caveats regarding this method:  **Make this PC discoverable** settings will not be available if you have UAC set to *Always notify*.  Also, **Make this PC discoverable** settings will not be available if you have a *Hyper-V virtual switch* configured with that Ethernet connection.

Answer (score 2):

Figured I'd chime in as well. My connection inadvertently was changed to Public, and when I would click the Private radio button in Windows' Network Settings, it would appear that the change was successful. However, exiting out and going back into the adapter settings I find that the change didn't save and was set back to Public.

I've tried using Powershell and even a network reset, but I just couldn't get it to work.

I was able to resolve this issue by going into my Firewall settings (I use a third party firewall) and I was able to change it there.

*Please enjoy my freehand circle*

[image]

I'm sure it's probably a bug in the firewall's software that locks down the changes out of it's UI, but regardless it works and hopefully does for the next person to wander here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this, was having the same issue. You saved the day man.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem (missing options) and all mentioned solutions did not work:

- Registry did already show Private/1 for the connection
- PowerShell command would change settings, but they would be lost on WiFi reconnect/restart
- Removal of connection, hiding and then searching again did not work
- No 3rd party firewall used, but disabling Windows Defender did not change anything

**The solution in my case was to have a working Internet connection.** While the device was connected to a singular (offline) WiFi Access Point (with either DHCP or static assignment), the problem persisted.

When connecting the AP to the wider network and to a gateway to the Internet, the options in the settings dialogue instantly appeared and could be set as expected.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my issue. But this is annoying. Why is it only available with an internet connection? I have a situation where I don't want/need internet on a network, and I keep having to constantly tell the computers on the network to treat the network as private.