# can't ping a Windows 10 through Ubuntu both connected to the same switch

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-10, ping, tcp

so I have connected both machines to the same switch. both have internet through ethernet and are in the same network. I am trying to connect to Windows 10 it is not working. So I decided to test using ping and ping gets stuck. Feedbacks are really appreciated.
[image]

```
mona@pascal:~$ ping 144.92.237.225
PING 144.92.237.225 (144.92.237.225) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Comment: Did you ensure that your Windows 10 machine is using a Private network profile to allow ICMP traffic? [How do I force Windows 10 to see a network as private?](https://superuser.com/questions/1160421/how-do-i-force-windows-10-to-see-a-network-as-private/1160433#1160433)

Comment: In windows 10, go to `Firewall` then `Advanced Settings`. Turn off the Domain Profile, Private profile and public profile and try again. If this works, it is a firewall issue and is usually the case. Can you also list the IP of the ubuntu machine and the IP of the windows machine?

Comment: They are both in the same private network. Linux machine IP address is 144.92.237.238

Comment: Just to check, when you right-click your network icon in the Notification Area and select `Open Network and Sharing Center`, the windows that appears specifically says that it is a `Private network`?

Comment: turned off the Firewall settings @narzard told and it pings now. Can you please write that as an answer? thanks

Comment: If you don't mind me saying so, you don't want to permanently turn off your firewall settings in that manner... it's a big security vulnerability, and Narzard had you do that simply to confirm that the firewall was the limiting factor.  If you ensure that you are using a Private network profile, it should also work while still maintaining an appropriate level of  network security.

Comment: @Run5k Agreed, just for diagnostic purposes. More secure answer posted.

Comment: @Narzard - yes, that is much more appropriate, but the Private network profile will allow ICMP traffic for IPV4 by default… and that's exactly what I was recommending in my very first reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make sure that ICMP for ipv4 is enabled on the inbound rules for your Private Network Firewall profile.

1. Open Windows Firewall
2. Choose `Advanced Settings`.
3. `Inbound Rules` on the left pane.
4. Find `File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)`.
5. Double click to open the properties and choose the `advanced` tab and make sure that `private` is checked.

Answer (score 1):

The asnwer aceppted doesn't work for me. I can't ping from my guest centos 8 vm to my host windows 10. VirtualBox has Bridged Network configured.

Host OS: windows 10 home single language
Version: 1909

Virtualbox 6.1.10:

- host: windows 10
- guest: centos 8

There exist 2 entries for `File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)`

[image]

Changing the first one to `Private` doesn't work.

Trurn off the firewall does work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also enable firewall rules on the command-line, using `netsh`. It is quite cumbersome, but can be useful if you need to do it on several machines or often.

Many useful rules are already pre-configured in the firewall, but not enabled by default.

To **enable `ping` only**, you can enable the "Core Networking Diagnostics" group of rules:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Core Networking Diagnostics" new enable=yes
```

To **enable "File and Printer Sharing"** there is a group of rules named just that, so :

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=yes
```

To list all inbound rules into a "my_firewall_rules.txt" file in your user directory :

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all dir=in > $HOME\my_firewall_rules.txt
```