# Windows 10 nevers asks for Private Or Public

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall

I have 2 machines I am have placed on their own network using a switch. These 2 machines are domain joined computers that normally sit on a domain network with DHCP. Using this switch I am making a small PRIVATE network between them. Over the past 2 days I found that they were unable to ping each other when on this small network because the network Profile is set to Public. I have done the PowerShell commands to set them to private but the firewall is still blocking communication.

How can I get these two domain joined computers to talk to each other on this small network. When connected to the small network and given IP address they did not ask of the domain was Public or Private and so it just defaulted to public "unknown network". The option in the network settings to change it to Private is also gone. Only option I have is Metered Connection. Why can't I change these connections to private and why even in private do they not talk to each other? GPO on the domain network does not have any firewall profiles.

Both machines are Windows 10 Professional 1709 x64. Both machines running Windows Defender Firewall. Even after using the Powershell command, on restart the profile will go back to Public which his not helpful.

Comment: Is this something different than the old windows firewall?  If not, set a different log file for each profile, pfirewall-DOMAIN.log, pfirewall-PRIVATE.log, and pfirewall-PUBLIC.log.   I want to say ICMP type communication is handled in a different part of the firewall configuration.   Private network settings can still block communication.

Comment: Are you certain that you are setting the network to Private?  Which Powershell command are you utilizing?  You might find that [changing the network to Private through the registry editor](https://superuser.com/a/1160433/650163) is another viable option.